# How to Use Logwatch With JBoss Logs

Tags: jboss, logwatch

I'm successfully using Logwatch for Tomcat and Apache but not for JBoss.  For some reason Logwatch can not access any files under the JBoss directory.  Is there anything I can do to make this work?  I'm trying to use Logwatch with JBoss nohup.out and server.log

Note - I can copy the JBoss log file to another directory outside of the JBoss directory and Logwatch can read the file.

I was considering using Logrotate to copy the log files to another directory but there appears to be issues in using Logrotate with JBoss logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work broadly the same as for tomcat, although JBoss does its own logging thing, which is undoubtedly a bad thing if you have two processes trying to do similar things.

It's the periodic-rotating-file-handler section of standalone.xml on Wildfly at least - you probably want to disable that if you're using logwatch.